# Function in a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I've got a (google) map with several markers. The coordinates and descriptions for these markers are stored in an object, the markers are created in a loop. Now I want to add a click event to each of these markers with the "key" value as a link target. Here is my code snippet:

the object:

```
$localstorage.setObject('lsStations', {
    "STA": {lat: '50.93358', lng: '6.57', name: 'Station A'},
    "STB": {lat: '50.9332', lng: '6.56690', name: 'Station B'},
    "STC": {lat: '50.934', lng: '6.566', name: 'Station C'}
});
```

creating the map and the markers:

```
.controller('GMapsCtrl', function ($scope, $localstorage) {
    'use strict';

    // initialize variables
    var map,
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.93358, 6.56692),
        stationCoords = $localstorage.getObject('lsStations');

    $scope.init = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            // default center
            center: myLatLng,
            // disable google maps ui
            disableDefaultUI: 1
        },
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions),
            marker = [],
            index,
            key;

        for (key in stationCoords) {
            if (stationCoords.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                // add marker for station
                marker[key] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(stationCoords[key].lat, stationCoords[key].lng),
                    map: map,
                    title: stationCoords[key].name
                });
                // add click event for each marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker[key], 'click', function () {
                    $scope.startStation = key;
                    alert(key);
                }
            )}
        }
    };   
    $scope.init();
});
```

When I click on any marker the alert text is "STC" instead of "STA" for the first, "STB" for the second and "STC" for the third marker. Thus I tried to place the function code outside of the loop:

```
.controller('GMapsCtrl', function ($scope, $localstorage) {
    'use strict';

    // initialize variables
    var map,
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.93358, 6.56692),
        stationCoords = $localstorage.getObject('lsStations');

    $scope.init = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            // default center
            center: myLatLng,
            // disable google maps ui
            disableDefaultUI: 1
        },
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions),
            marker = [],
            index,
            key;

        function createMarker() {
            $scope.startStation = key;
            alert(key);
            //window.location.href = '#/station/' + key;
        }

        for (key in stationCoords) {
            if (stationCoords.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                // add marker for station
                marker[key] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(stationCoords[key].lat, stationCoords[key].lng),
                    map: map,
                    title: stationCoords[key].name
                });
                // add click event for each marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker[key], 'click', createMarker(key));
            }
        }
    };    
    $scope.init();  
});
```

With this code the alert dialogues got the right text ("STA", "STB" and "STC"). But they are all fired when the page is loaded and nothing happens if I'm clicking on the markers.

How can I assign a click event for each marker with the different key values for each marker?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to apply my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure (this is based on the idea of the guy that posted a suggestion and then deleted it)

```
createMarkersForRecommendations = function() {
  return stationCoords.forEach(function(rec, idx) {
    var thisPoint;
    thisPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(rec.lat, rec.lng);
    map.markers[idx] = new google.maps.Marker({
      title: rec.rname,
      position: thisPoint,
      icon: rec.icon,
    });
    map.markers[idx].setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map.markers[idx], "click", (function(ix) {
      if (Restos.debug) {
        console.log(ix + 1, map.markers[ix].getTitle());
      }
      return $scope.$apply();     // as a google maps click event does not trigger an angluar digest
    }).bind(null, idx));
  });
};
```

Comment: Sry, I wasn't able to get your code working, maybe I haven't understood it right. Seemed like a quite clean solution. Still, your answer helped me to understand my problem - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I changed Aqib Mapari's code snippet a bit and now it is working:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[key], 'click', function () {
    var thisMarker;
    for (thisMarker in marker) {
        if (marker[thisMarker] === this) {
            // link to detail page for selected marker
            window.location.href = '#/station/' + thisMarker;
        }
    }                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think there may be an easier way - I think you already have the closure, but are just not using it correctly

```
   function createMarker(key) {
                  //     ^^^
        $scope.startStation = key;
        alert(key);
        //window.location.href = '#/station/' + key;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try making this change in your on click function. It worked for me.

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[key], 'click', function () {
for(var j=0; j<marker.length; j++){
    if(marker[j] == this){
        $scope.startStation = key;
        alert(key);
    }
}                    
});
```

Thanks.